# If $f'(a)$ is injective, then there is an open set $V$ where $f$ is injective

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-analysis

I'm trying to prove that an immersion $f:U\subset\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^m$ is a local homeomorphism. I was able to show that if $f$ is injective, then $f$ is homeomorphism, so if I can prove that there is an open set $V_a$, for each $a\in U$, where $f$ is injective, and so $f|_{V_a}$ is a homeomorphism.

I've tryied to suppose that for every open set $a\in V$, there is a $y\in V$ such $f(y)=f(a)$ and then get an absurd, but I was not able.

I don't even know if its true that $f'(a)$ injective implies locally injective, but it feels right.

Any hint, or counter example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I recall correctly, your intuition is correct -- $f$ is an immersion at a point if and only if $f$ is locally injective at that point (ie. there exists some neighbourhood of that point on which $f$ is injective).  

I am not quite sure how this should give you a bijection though... Are you sure you did not mean to say $f$ is an open map (which I am sure is true)?

Comment: I've already proved that if $f$ is an injection, then $f$ is an open map. I want to show that every point has a neighborhood where $f$ is injective, so the result follows.

Ps.: The definition that I'm using of immesrsion is that $f'(x)$ is injective for every $x$ in $U$.

Comment: Note that it does not suffice to show that $f$ an injection implies that $f$ is open, because $f$ an immersion only shows that $f$ is a _local_ injection which does not imply that $f$ is a global injection.

Comment: But I'm trying to proof that is a local homeomorphism, i.e., for every $a\in U$, there is an open set $V\subset U$, where $f|_V$ is homeomorphic to $f(V)$, so I don need to $f$ be a global injection. I've already prooved that $f$ injective in an open set $V$ and $f$ immersion, then $f$ is open. So I just have to find this opens sets $V$ for each $a\in U$, where $f$ is injective

Comment: Are you allowed to use the inverse function theorem?

Comment: Yes, actually, when I prooved $f$ open I used the local form of immersions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is $C^1$and $f'(a)$ is injective. Then $f'(a)(\mathbb R^n)$ is an $n$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m .$ We can choose a linear $T: \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^{n}$ such that $T$ is injective on $(f'(a)(\mathbb R^n)).$ Then $T\circ f$ is a $C^1$ mapping of $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^{n}.$  Note that $(T \circ f)'(a) = T\circ f'(a),$ which is nonsingular. By the inverse function theorem, $T\circ f$ is injective in a neighborhood $V_a.$ This implies $f$ is injective in $V_a$ as desired.

---

Previous answer: A differentiable (but not $C^1$) example: On the real line, let $f(x) = x + 2x^2\sin (1/x), a = 0.$ Then $f'(a)$ is injective, but $f$ is not injective in any neighborhood of $a.$

Comment: But this function is not $C^1$, and immersions are $C^1$.

Comment: @e.turatti I've editied my answer.